# How to minimize quartic function for regularizing commutativity?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, regularization, quartics

My objective is regularizing a function over $X\in \mathbb{R}^{I\times J}$ such that its covariance is jointly diagonalizable with a positive semi-definite matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{I\times I}$. For this, I am trying to minimize an objective with commutativity between the covariance of $X$ and $A$. The objective roughly looks like:
\begin{gather}
f(X)+\|XX^\top A- AXX^\top\|_F^2,
\end{gather}
where $X$ is assumed to be zero mean. My problem is finding an optimizer rather than strictly solving the form I propose. So I am open to change the Frobenius norm of the regularization to some other norm if helpful.

I am planning on using an [augmented Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Lagrangian_method) to introduce auxiliary variables to separate regularization from $f(X)$. This changes my function for the regularization to something like:
\begin{gather}
\delta\|X-Y-\Lambda\|_F^2+\|YY^\top A- AYY^\top\|_F^2.
\end{gather}

I have came upon [polynomial sum of squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_SOS) in my search but couldn't represent my function in that form.

My questions (*any of them is sufficient for me*) are:

1. Could a gradient descent approach minimize this function as it is quartic in $Y$?
2. If this was quadratic, I would have solved this by setting the derivative to zero but in this case the derivative is a cubic function, so it would have multiple roots. Would it suffice to select any root?
3. Would it make it easier to use $\ell_1$-norm rather than Frobenius norm to find an optimizer?

*Notes: I am an electrical engineer and this is my first question on StackExchange. Please let me know if I missed anything.*

Comment: If the objective is non-convex, gradient descent can only give you a local minimizer.  How large are $I$ and $J$?

Comment: Amir Ali Ahmadi, Alex Olshevsky, Pablo A. Parrilo, John N. Tsitsiklis, [NP-hardness of deciding convexity of quartic polynomials and related problems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1908), December 2010.

Comment: $X$ is a matricized tensor, so I would say $J>>I$ in most cases. It is hard to point out how large the $I$ is as the optimization aims to solve a general framework.

Comment: Have you considered the case where $I=J=1$?

Comment: I didn't. Commutativity of the covarience (in that case, varience) doesn't make sense in that case.

Comment: Do I understand it right that in the second optimization problem (with $Y$) $X$ and $\Lambda$ are some fixed matrices and the optimization is done in $Y$?